# Rigid body flying into air rather than dropping down

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody, cell-fracture

Whenever I add rigid body to a fragment of a Pawn chess piece that has been Cell Fractured, the piece doesn't drop straight down but instead flies around. However when I copy the Pawn piece into a clean blender file, the piece acts normally and simply drops down. When I delete everything from the original file aside from the one Pawn piece the segment is still flying off rather than dropping down.

Does anyone have any idea what is causing this to happen? I have created a cube, cell fractured it and then added a rigid body and this dropped down normally.

Link to the blender file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eSL1juBPI2BIuv1Z-bULypo6pbwBFUz9/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please try this link: <https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eSL1juBPI2BIuv1Z-bULypo6pbwBFUz9/view?usp=sharing>

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work for the moment, if you remove the Rigid Body world and recreate one (in the Scene panel) and regive a Rigid Body to the piece it will work again

Comment: Hey khazag169.

Please avoid using Google Drive links and instead use: https://blend-exchange.com/ to upload your `.blend` files